# Data repeating itself when i gathered it from Firebase Realtime for my Telegram bot

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I gather my data from Firebase RealTime Database to Telegram bot with Button and its showing perfectly, but when i click on the button one more time the data just repeat itself, but not updates

Code for data gathering:

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
db = firebase.database()
result = []
maps = db.child().get()

def collect_maps():
    for map in maps.each():
        id = db.child(map.key()).child('id').get()
        name = db.child(map.key()).child('name').get()
        longitude = db.child(map.key()).child('longitude').get()
        latitude = db.child(map.key()).child('latitude').get()

        result.append(
            {
                'id': id.val(),
                'name': name.val(),
                'longitude': longitude.val(),
                'latitude': latitude.val()
            }
        )
    return result
```

Code for message handler:

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Get Maps'))
async def get_maps(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Please wait a bit...')


    data = collect_maps()

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    key = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Get Location', callback_data='Get Location')
    keyboard.add(key)

    user_id = message.from_user.id

    await message.answer('Your maps, that i collected:')
    for index, item in enumerate(data):
        card = f'{index+1}) {item.get("id")} - {item.get("name")}\n' \
            f'Longitude: {item.get("longitude")}\n' \
            f'Latitude: {item.get("latitude")}\n'

        await message.answer(card, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply putting data base var into the function

```
def collect_maps():
    db = firebase.database()
    result = []
    maps = db.child().get()
    for map in maps.each():
        id = db.child(map.key()).child('id').get()
        name = db.child(map.key()).child('name').get()
        longitude = db.child(map.key()).child('longitude').get()
        latitude = db.child(map.key()).child('latitude').get()

        result.append(
            {
                'id': id.val(),
                'name': name.val(),
                'longitude': longitude.val(),
                'latitude': latitude.val()
            }
        )
    return result
```